# Why is there no Gnome Shell package for Natty?

Tags: 11.04, gnome

Aside from a PPA. Is it not currently being worked on, or is there lack of something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK, Ubuntu is still not ready for the whole GTK3+ shift (it's supposed to be for natty+1) and proposing a recent gnome-shell package would break a lot of applications, so for the time being, a PPA is the way to go.

- This [status report](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2011-January/002740.html) from the mailing list has all the information you need

Comment: Instead of saying Ubuntu is not ready, we should say that GNOME3 and GTK+3 isn't ready for Ubuntu, as they are still unstable.

Comment: @Toki I edited your comment. Mind your language here please.

Comment: What? I see exactly the same commented I posted.

Comment: @Toki It wasn't a big edit. You swore in the original version. It might seem petty but we try to keep the site as clean as possible.

Comment: The mailing list information was perfect, thank you

Comment: @Oli, I'm sorry but I don't remember using any swear words, at least not intentionally.